# Is there a method to get the height of the entire 'ScrollView'?

Tags: android, android-layout, height, scrollview

Is there a method in Android to get the height of the entire 'ScrollView'?

I tried 'layout.getMeasuredHeight()' but it gives the height only of the visible region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the height of the ScrollView's child. Try `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight()`.

**EDIT**

You could possibly try having the View measure itself and give it a measurespec that lets it use as much space as it wants. Something like this:

```
int width = ... // get screen width;
int height = 65536; // arbitrarily large value
final int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
final int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
view.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
// now get the height
int measuredHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Full disclosure: I don't know if this will work or what effect it may have in your app. There is a side-effect of calling this method, which is that the view's measured dimensions are set. If it's possible, you might try to create a separate, duplicate view and measure that one; or, after you do this measuring hack, call `requestLayout()` on the view to schedule another measure & layout of the view tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not give the exact height. I'm converting the ScrollView to an png. Although, using the height of the child gives a better result then using the ScrollView height itself, the height is still not correct. It tends not to cover the whole view! Please advise.

Comment: One idea that might work (though perhaps a bit hacky) would be asking the View to measure itself. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView always has only one child, so using:

```
ScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
```

should work.